# How can I restrict count of rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how can I restrict count of rows, I mean I have table which is `users` and I want to set a limit for example 10 so 10 must be the top limit of count. How can I do that ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You need to use a trigger

Comment: could you spesify it ? what do you mean by trigger ?

Comment: what do you mean by limit count? do you mean limit the number of rows returned? or you are counting rows and you want the max count to be 10?

Comment: I want to have maximum 10 users, I think it's more clear now.

Comment: have you made any attempts? any sql code you have? maybe something like this? `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10;`

Comment: this gives me 10 rows from table,as I said, I need to restrict it to 10. I mean there shouldn't be 11. row.

Comment: So you want to prevent inserting more rows after your maximum of 10 is reached?

Comment: @BenGrimm yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the number of rows in a specific table with PostgreSQL?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17518182/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CHECK constraint on an id number.

```
create table users (
  user_id integer primary key
    check (user_id between 1 and 10),
  user_name varchar(35) not null
);
```

I think you're better off with an integer than with `serial` for this, since you're using only 10 rows.